# rgba Not Working Correctly in IE10 Compatibility, IE8, or Chrome

Tags: css

I have a stylesheet as follows:

```
        .blue {
            background: #B0C4DE;
        }

        .green {
            background: #a4d5a8;
        }
        .purple {
            background: #ada4d4;
        }
        .pink {
            background: #e3b3e0;
        }
        .yellow {
            background: #e0e3ab;
        }
        tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td{
            background: #FFFFFF; /*fallback color */
            background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .50);
        }
```

I'd like to have columns grouped by color with alternating row opacity to create the zebra stripe effect.  I do this by assigning CSS classes to each column, no inline styles here, and using the `nth-child(odd)` CSS selector in conjunction with the `rgba` attribute.

However, in both IE10 with compatibility mode and Chrome, the following grid is rendered, with alternating rows of color and white:

[image]

In IE8, it seems that the `rgba` attribute is ignored:

[image]

Is my CSS incorrect?  Is there anything else I could include that would help with debugging?  I've created this application in .NET, so I unfortunately cannot link to a fiddle.

EDIT:  The white rows are erroneous.  They should be a slightly lighter shade of the column grouping color.  See http://cssdeck.com/labs/6rgab657 for an example.

EDIT:  In the below image of the Chrome Inspector, I would assume that the selector would override the blue class, and only alter the opacity of the original color so that it would be slightly lighter.  Am I incorrect in my assumption?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: The alpha parameter [isn't supported](http://caniuse.com/css3-colors) in IE8

Comment: @Adrift I should have known that, do you have any idea why Chrome and IE10 Compatibility mode are coloring the cells in white?

Comment: Well the last selector is using the `odd` keyword within `:nth-child()` wouldn't that be the expected behaviour? Or am I overlooking something (very likely :p)

Comment: It is my understanding that the rows should be a slightly more transparent color than the CSS class they are overriding.  For instance, the white rows in columns 1-4 would be a slightly lighter green than the other rows, the white rows in columns 5-8 would be a slightly lighter purple than the other rows, etc.  See http://cssdeck.com/labs/6rgab657 for an example.  Is this the case?

Comment: It's hard to answer without seeing your HTML as well, but I think you're misunderstanding the way your selector works. The `.green` class is highlighting the whole column green, but then the `tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td` selector is overriding only the *odd* rows and coloring them white. Does that make any sense?

Comment: Yes, I understand how the selector works.  I think what I'm misunderstanding is how the selector interacts with the CSS class it is overriding.  For instance, in the CSS Deck link I posted above, the selector creates a slightly lighter shade of the original color, rather than white.  In my page, it is overriding the color and setting it to white, regardless of the `rgba` value that I use.  See latest edit with Chrome inspector showing the classes.

Comment: In the CSS deck you're applying the `:nth-child(odd)` selector to the entire `<tr>` not the odd `<td>` elements like you are in the CSS you posted.

Comment: Good point.  .NET compiles the code in a way that it assigns the CSS color classes to each individual table cell, rather than the column I set the CSS class on.  This must be why it isn't working.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Adrift, IMO, this shouldn't make difference. According [to the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#table-layers), both `tr` and `td` backgrounds should be stacked above the `colgroup` background. If the color class was applied to the `td` directly, it shouldn't work in other browsers as well.

Comment: "In the below image of the Chrome Inspector, I would assume that the selector would override the blue class, and only alter the opacity of the original color so that it would be slightly lighter. Am I incorrect in my assumption?"  That would be an incorrect assumption.  You want to just use opacity if you only want to make it slightly lighter, otherwise your rgba values are a semi-transparent white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by adding specific styles for each color's `nth-child(odd)` selector:

```
        .blue {
            background: #B0C4DE;
        }

        .green {
            background: #a4d5a8;
        }
        .purple {
            background: #ada4d4;
        }
        .pink {
            background: #e3b3e0;
        }
        .yellow {
            background: #e0e3ab;
        }

        /*Color the odd rows with a lighter shade
        maintains zebra stripe while sorting via jQuery*/
        tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td.blue{
            background: #E6E6FA;
        }
        tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td.green{
            background: #ddf5de;
        }
        tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td.purple{
            background: #c7c6f4;
        }
        tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td.pink{
            background: #fae1fa;
        }
        tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td.yellow{
            background: #f5f8dd;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

RGBA is not supported in IE8 it only supports solid colors.

http://css-tricks.com/rgba-browser-support/

Answer (score 1):

IE8 and below ("Compatibility mode" is a tricky kind of IE7 emulation) support neither `rgba` color notation nor `:nth-child` CSS selector. There are some workarounds for semi-transparent backgrounds for them (e.g. [auto-generating of one-pixel PNG](http://lea.verou.me/rgba.php/) or using [IE propritary `filter` property](http://kilianvalkhof.com/2010/css-xhtml/how-to-use-rgba-in-ie/)).

Chrome may have problems with backgrounds of table cells (e.g. it applies the background to the whole `tr` incorrectly), but your CSSdesk example works correctly for me in both Chrome 28 and Chrome Canary 30 (as well as in Safari 5.1 Win7). The cells seem to have both `colgroup` and `td` backgrounds stacked one onto another (as per [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#table-layers)). So I have no explanation to the Chrome issue assuming that Chrome and other browsers get the same markup.